# (Excel - power query M) WeekOfYear don't return the good numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I'm trying to use "Date.WeekOfYear()" but for some reasons the week number returned seems wrong.

for exemple : [Year = 2021 & Month = 01]

```
WeekNbr = Number.ToText(Date.WeekOfYear(#date(Year, Month, 1), Day.Monday))
```

In this exemple I'm trying to get the week number of the "1st january 2021" who is "53" but the formula return 1.

and when I try with the date "4/01/2021" who is the first day of 2021 so the actual first week the formula return 2 ...

Any advises ?

Comment: How did you came up with jan 1st being the 53 week of the year?

Comment: thanks to google : https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021 The first week of 2021 start at 04/01/2021 and end at 10/01/2021. I'm using ISO-8601

Comment: Power Query does not have a built-in `ISOweeknumber` function.  You will need to write your own. Or see [M functions to convert between ISO 8601 Week & Year ⇄ dates](https://gist.github.com/r-k-b/18d898e5eed786c9240e3804b167a5ca)

Comment: Damn that's why ... thanks

Comment: thanks a lot @Ron Rosenfeld for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerQuery function that should return the ISO Weeknumber.

*(This algorithm works in VBA and seems to work in PQ)*

```
(theDate as date) =>
let
   a = Date.AddDays(theDate,-1),
   b = Date.DayOfWeek(a,Day.Sunday),
   c = Date.AddDays(theDate,-b + 3),
   d2 = #date(Date.Year(c),1,3),
   IWN  =  Number.IntegerDivide(Number.From(theDate)-Number.From(d2) + Date.DayOfWeek(d2)+6,7)
in
    IWN
```